# How can I decode a binary file when I don't know the proper encoding?

Tags: decode

I have a .bin file that I would like to decode, but I don't know how it was encoded.  Opening with notepad yields crazy jumbled text like this:

`´èà¼©ôÉœ‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡‡†U‡gÎÓL¥:†ÊéõŽÕÄU‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡ÊéõŽ«§Áàæé]©§…ÈòH´èè…ÐâÍ…Æ÷I‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡÷Ž”²¶YÕ´©ŽÐóëŽ¸ì©¸ê¨ŽØæ¨U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡‡†U‡aîñL¥:†ÊéõŽÕÄU‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡ÉÔáëä§ª]Xæó¤§ÓÀ…ÔïŽØô§†¼ëîÎ«§€€óäO…ÊèÈ âô]8éë¼â‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡ðˆØ©éÔáëä©äŽ°¨‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡‡†U‡÷Ð.LL¥:†ÊéõŽÕÄU‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡ÅN€äì]\âîN…Åõ”âô]Læã¸§ª]4îôHé§H¸§ÅN€äì]\âîN…Åõ”âô^…Áõ§èÎ…×æÎ”èõ
…ÎéHõéÔ§Õ
”îèU‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡ðˆØ©÷
¼ãèÉ€©äŽ°¨ôH€óîŽ¼¨÷N€þ¨ÙÍµ±XÑ°´Å¿°ÙÕµ¾å·‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡‡†U‡çã“ÞK¥:†ÊéõŽÕÄU‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡‡U‡×
¼ãèÉ€§Õ
”`

My understanding is that notepad is trying to use the wrong decoding method, resulting in incorrect characters.  If there is a program or website where I can just copy the text and try a bunch of methods of decoding I would really appreciate a link.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, Google certainly gives results for "detect encoding online", but I doubt a .bin file contains text. I suggest you run a file format identifying program on it, e.g. [TrIDNet](http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html). That might prove it to be binary. Notepad++ also does automatic encoding detection, as do web browsers. You could rename the file and drop it into Notepad++ or Firefox.

Comment: I tried using notepad++ but had no luck.  I know the contents of the file is text; it contains web history. I will try TrIDNet and see what happens. @Norman

Comment: I scanned with TrIDNet and got 0.0% match.. Any other suggestions @Norman

Comment: Well, unless your text file is confidential, let's try some [online encoding detectors](https://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projects/chared/). Or another [program](https://encodingchecker.codeplex.com/). Or I might write a little python script trying all encodings known to Python, but then you'd need to look at the results and find the good one yourself.

Comment: No luck with either of those.  Do you think the application that created the file uses its own encoding system or maybe it is encrypted?

Comment: Not unlikely. Privacy is trending. Knowing which browser created the file might help. Also, Firefox e.g. uses SQLite databases to store history data, and that's a binary format even though only text data is contained.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Notepad++ install the plugin for hex editor. Once you have that, all you need to do is some kind of combination and permutation, depending upon what kind of data is held in you binary file (also while doing it keep in mind the byte order little or big endian).